# Populate ComboboxList client side using ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

Ok so i'm using this piece of AJAX code

```
xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.open('POST', '/AllPoints.aspx', false);
xhr2.setRequestHeader('kml_file', path);
```

And what I'm doing server side is this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Headers["kml_file"]))
            {
                DataTable dt = GetDataSet().Tables[0];

                CBList_Pontos_Repetidos.DataSource = dt;
                CBList_Pontos_Repetidos.DataTextField = dt.Columns[1].ToString();
                CBList_Pontos_Repetidos.DataValueField = dt.Columns[0].ToString();
                CBList_Pontos_Repetidos.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
```

And everything runs fine and by debugging I can see all the code is being executed, problem is, it's all server side and there's no actual postback, async or not, so nothing is shown client-side, I can only see it server side.

I've been around and around this and I can't seem to figure out the solution, any help?

PS: I've edited all the unnecessary strings of code so you can understand it better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at accessing asp.net page methods through ajax. Here's a helpful [link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: I've seen nearly everything there is and I still can't figure out how to solve this problem. Any actual help on my code rather than links?